# Stokes' Theorem Example sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

Been asked to use Stokes' theorem to solve the integral:

$\int _C x dx + (x - 2yz)dy + (x^2 + z)dz $ where C is the intersection between $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=x$ and the half space $z>0$.

Just really not sure how to tackle this or how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would anyone compute this integral ($=:J$) using Stokes' theorem? The curve in question goes around the cylinder $\bigl(x-{1\over2}\bigr)^2+y^2={1\over4}$ and stays all the time on the upper half of $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. It follows that a parametric representation of $C$ (we are free to choose its sense of direction) is given by
$$t\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{x(t)&={1\over2}+{1\over2}\cos t \cr
y(t)&={1\over2}\sin t\cr
z(t)&=\sqrt{1-x^2(t)-y^2(t)}=\sqrt{1-x(t)}=\sin{t\over2}\cr}\right.\qquad(0\leq t\leq2\pi)\ .$$
As $\int_Cx\>dx=\int_Cz\>dz=0$ it remains to compute
$$J=\int_C(x-2yz)\>dy+\int_C x^2\>dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\bigl((x(t)-2y(t)z(t))y'(t)+x^2(t)z'(t)\bigr)\>dt\ .$$
Mathematica obtained $J={\pi\over4}$.

Comment: Yes that worked brilliantly, i totally forgot about the trip identity for z, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Warning: This solution uses Stoke's theorem in language of differential forms like
$$\int\limits_{\partial A} \omega   = \int\limits_A {d\omega }$$

$\partial A = C$ is the bounding curve of an surface-area say $A$ given by:

$$\begin{array}{l}
{x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2} = 1\\
{x^2} + {y^2} = x\\
z > 0
\end{array}$$

Also given a 1-Form
$$\omega  = xdx + (x - 2yz)dy + ({x^2} + z)dz$$
on the boundary.

For exterior derivative we get

$$d\omega  = dx \wedge dy + 2(xdx + ydy) \wedge dz$$

Because
$$
{x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2} = 1
$$
observe that:

$$xdx + ydy + zdz = 0$$

and

$$\begin{array}{l}
d\omega  = dx \wedge dy + 2(xdx + ydy) \wedge dz\\
 = dx \wedge dy + 2(xdx + ydy + zdz - zdz) \wedge dz\\
 = dx \wedge dy
\end{array}$$

Apply now RHS of Stoke's theorem. To calculate RHS, we choose polar-coordinates as follows:

$$\left. \begin{gathered}
  x = r\cos (\varphi ) \hfill \\
  y = r\sin (\varphi ) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right\}dx \wedge dy = \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\cos (\varphi )}&{\sin (\varphi )} \\ 
  { - r\sin (\varphi )}&{r\cos (\varphi )} 
\end{array}} \right|dr \wedge d\varphi  = rdr \wedge d\varphi$$

and we are done very quickly:

$$\int\limits_A {dx \wedge dy}  = \int\limits_B {rdr \wedge d\varphi }  = \int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{2}} {rdrd\varphi } }  = 2\pi  \cdot \frac{1}{8} = \frac{\pi }{4}$$

[image: Region A bounded by C]

Comment: if it is viewed from above and we go counterclockwise, would this make it negative?

Comment: @snowman: Counterclockwise is positive orientation. Moving along
$C$ counterclockwise means, the surface is always LHS.

Comment: By the way: Solution from Christian Blatter didn't use Stoke's theorem.