# using stokes thm on cylinder and sphere intersection

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Use Stoke's theorem to solve the following integral (each time the curve is oriented counterclockwise when viewed from above):
$$\int \limits_C xdx +(x-2yz)dy+(x^2+z)dz$$ where $C$ is the intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, the cylinder $x^2+y^2=x$, and the halfspace $z>0$.

I let $y=r\cos\theta$, and let $z=r\sin\theta$ which makes $x=1-r^2\sin^2\theta$ so $$S(r,\theta)=(1-r^2\sin^2\theta, r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$$ with $r\in[0,1]$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$

I got the normal $n=(r,0, 2r^2 \sin\theta)$ and

curl($F$)$=(2y,-2x,1)=(2r\cos\theta, -2-2r^2 \sin^2 \theta, 1)$

but when I take the dot product of these two and double integrate, I end up with zero which seems wrong. Please help.

Comment: You don't explain what $S(r,\theta)$ is meant to be. In any case it  neither represents part of the sphere nor of the cylinder. Stokes' theorem refers to a surface $S$ and its boundary curve $\partial S$. – We had the same question yesterday, see here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194168/stokes-theorem-example-sphere/1194437#1194437

Comment: wait i didn't ask the same question yesterday.... where did you get that from

Comment: @snowman: Be sure, to use Stoke's theorem.